# How to enable OAuth extension in laradock using nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, oauth, laradock

I have set up docker with laradock.

I'm trying to connect to a REST service, but I need the OAuth extension installed in order to execute:

`$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);`

How do I inatall/enable this extension on Laradock?

Thank you!